# opencv 2.4.8 is not importing

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, import

As i am doing background subtraction on a video, opencv 2.4.6 is not supporting, like web cam will not respond. 
 my guide suggested me to download and install opencv 2.4.8, and i did so, but it is giving me an error

```
ImportError
<ipython-input-1-72fbbcfe2587> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv2

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

i have uninstalled the earlier version and then i have installed the new version, and done all the prerequisites.

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV relies on numpy, do you have numpy installed?

Comment: numpy will be included automatically, i'm using enthought canopy.